# Работа с файлами в Python. С чего начать?

Tags: python

Я как новичок изучающий Python, быстро дошёл до момента , когда довольно обширная, как мне кажется, тема "Работа с файлами" ввела меня в тупик. Я прочитал документацию на Metanit`е & pythonworld, но позже подыскивая практические занятия , оказалось , что там многое не договаривают.
Суть вопроса : *Подскажите план изучения темы "Работа с файлами"*

Comment: Да просто пробуйте читать, а потом писать текстовые, а потом двоичные файлы. Всё.

Comment: на чем затупили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас пишу учебник по прогаммированию на **Python**, помогли направиться на тему, спасибо за вопрос)

### Как записать текст в файл?

Для этого впишите код:

```
a='Любой текст'
test=open('test1.txt', 'w')
test.write(a)
test.close()
```

Функция `open` открывает любой файл, который можно прочитать в **Python** (кроме недопустимых расширений). Не беспокойтесь, если такого файла нет, так как в таком случает программа создаст новый файл. Если же такой файл есть, то он должен лежать в той папке, где лежит ваша программа. Если вы хотите положить файл в другую папку, вам придётся указывать полный путь к файлу, вот так (на **Windows**):

```
test=open('C:\\Users\\имя пользователя\\...')
```

Но что означает буква `'w'` в конце функции `open`? Это значит, что файл открывается для *перезаписи*, то есть весь текст из файла удаляется и в файл добавляется текст. Если вы хотите, чтобы файл открывался для *дозаписи*, замените `'w'` на `'a'`.

### Как прочитать файл?

Давайте прочитаем наш файл прямо в оболочке **Python**. Для этого запишите код:

```
test=open('test1.txt')
print(test.read())
```

Если вы запустите программу, она выведет текст из файла. Обратите внимание, что при чтении файла ни `'w'` ни `'a'` в конце функции `open` писать не нужно.

### Вот план изучения:

1. Почитайте больше книг. Лично посоветую книгу *Джейсона Бриггса* **"PYTHON для детей"**. Не обижайтесь, что для детей, там описаны многие полезные действия в **Python**, в том числе работа с файлами)
2. Почитайте интернет-документации на **[PythonDocs](https://docs.python.org/3/)**.
3. Почитайте интересные интернет-статьи про операции с файлами, одна из них **[тут](https://pythonim.ru/osnovy/operatsii-faylami-python#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20Python%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B%3A)**.